# frontier of class $C^{1}$.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, differential-geometry

Studying the Divergence Theorem (Gauss theorem), found the definition of frontier of class $C^{1}$. Which means? That is, the one which is a set with boundary of class $C^{1}$?

Can give reference books.

grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation in more elementary terms: an open set $A$ has boundary of class $C^1$ if  for every point $p$  on the boundary of $A$ there exist:

- a function $f$ of $n-1$ variables, with continuous first-order derivatives
- a number $r>0$
- an invertible linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$

such that $A\cap \{x:|x-p|<r\} = \{Tu:u_n>f(u_1,\dots,u_{n-1})\}\cap \{x:|x-p|<r\}$.

Unfortunately I don't have an accessible reference for this, apart from Wikipedia article on the aforementioned [manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold).

Comment: The appendix of the Evans's book "Partial Differential Equations" have a definition of boundary of class $C^k$ which close to that you gave.

Answer (score 2):

This is the notion of submanifold. A $C^1$ submanifold of dimension $p$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that "locally looks like $\mathbb{R}^p$", the straightening being of regularity at least $C^1$. More precisely :

A set $M$ is a $C^1$ submanifold if for every $x \in M$ there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ and a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $\phi : U \rightarrow V$ ($V$ being an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$) which sends $U \cap M$ to $(\mathbb{R}^p \times \{0\}^{n-p}) \cap V$ and $x$ to 0.

Examples: the sphere in the 3-dimensional space, a torus, a cylinder...

Comment: as a side note, in my experience, it is not essential for people who work in EDPs to have a fine knowlodge of manifolds. the important thing is, manifolds are designed so that you can do differential calculs on them.